# Max Group in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have this table in Power BI (numbers are random) I'm new to Power BI/DAX but have some SQL experience.

| County | Description | 1969 | 1970 | 1971 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Abbeville | Personal Income | 12341234 | 12341234 | 12341234 |
| Abbeville | Earnings by place of work | 1234 | 1234 | 1234 |
| Aiken | Personal Income | 93833 | 7230 | 829349 |
| Aiken | Earnings by place of work | 783489 | 12312 | 2134 |
| Richland | Personal Income | 89384987 | 72389494 | 9389449 |
| Richland | Government social insurance | 293403 | 890394 | 893994 |
| Richland | Earnings by place of work | 93438 | 89843 | 23423 |

I need to find the max description for each county, for each year, and then I'll color code a fill map accordingly, so it should look like this:

| County | Description | 1969 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Abbeville | Personal Income | 12341234 |
| Aiken | Earnings by place of work | 783489 |
| Richland | Personal Income | 89384987 |

The actual table has over 20 descriptions per county and ranges from 1969 - 2021.

Comment: For "Aiken", you have bigger value 829349 in "Personal Income". Why your output have "Earnings by place of work"?

Answer (score 0):

First problem is that your table structure isn't quite right. You need to unpivot the year columns so that you end up with (County, Income Source, Year, Amount).
After that (this is where people are gonna whine about how I did it), I created these measures:

```
total Amount = SUM('Sheet1'[Amount])

Income Source Rank = RANKX(
ALLEXCEPT('Sheet1','Sheet1'[County],'Sheet1'[Year]),[total Amount],,DESC,Dense)
```

then I added a table to the canvas and put Country, Year, [Total Amount], [Income Source Rank] on columns, and filtered for [Income Source Rank]=1.

I'm thinking I was supposed to use FILTER() for the final table, though.